# How can I merge/link two video clips in Premiere?

Tags: video, premiere

Every time I search this problem in Google the only options are how to link audio clips to video or how to sync audio to video clips.

I need to combine/link/merge a picture to a video clip, so that if I edit one the same thing happens to the other clip, like merging layers in Photoshop.

Answer (score 9):

**MERGING VIDEO CLIPS**

To combine video clips there is something called Nested Sequence.

A very powerful technique.
When adding clips to a timeline you are working in what is called a sequence (normally named Sequence 01), drop your two clips into your timeline and rename your sequence 01 to something like 'My day trip to the market'.

Select a different video clip and drag and drop it onto the 'new item' button. Bottom right of the Project window.
That would create ANOTHER sequence which you can rename as your 'master sequence' from what would probably be called 'sequence 02'.

Now you can drag and drop your original sequence like a clip INTO your master sequence. And tada.

The wonderful thing about nested sequences is you can go back and re-edit it and it would update in all your other sequences where you use it.

**MERGING AUDIO AND VIDEO** (original answer regarding merging audio and video)

Import your clips into the project.
Select your video and audio clips (so they are both selected)
Right click and 'Merge Clips...'
It will ask to sync on in (start of audio and video) or out (end of audio and video).
Click ok and you would now have a merge file of both your video and audio clips that you can manipulate as a single clip.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No this doesn't work. `drag and drop your original sequence like a clip INTO your master sequence` won't let you, you can't drop one sequence into another. It simply places one sequence next to another.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up replacing the video clip with a after effects composition. then i added the picture to the clipping after effects and it was there in premiere as one clip.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what you're asking is possible but here are some ideas that might help.

**Linking the groups**: Well you can group the 2 files together Clip > Group.

**Applying a effect to multiple video clips**: If you want to copy the effects you can select the affected clip, copy the effect in the Effect Controls clip preview panel and simply paste it to the clips individually or select all the clips and ctrl+V or if your original clip has only that one effect (no opacity key framing etc) you can copy the clip and in the drop down panel (right click) select paste attributes.

You could also save the effect setting as an effect preset and then apply the new effect preset to other clips.

Answer (score 0):

highlight the two clips you'd like to combine, right click, go to "nest," and then create your new nested sequence :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes to LINK a title and clip you can right click, go to "nest," and then create your new nested sequence like KR1DL1 said above. This is the best and its awesome.

Link two clips, link video, premier pro cc, premier cc

Took me a while to find this.

Nesting.

Comment: It looks like you had intended to include some links to other sites but they appear to be missing. Can you add them and summarize their contents in case they become unavailable?